# save android device current ringtone into storage

Tags: android, uri, ringtone

I wanted to know if there is any way that I could save my device's current ringtone programmatically.

I'm getting my current ringtone like below:

```
Uri defaultRintoneUri = 
 RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

Ringtone currentRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
  getApplicationContext(), defaultRintoneUri);
```

But I don't know how to save it or if it's possible!